# mostrar una función js dentro de un archivo php

Tags: javascript, php, html5

hola muy buenas necesito ayuda con un problema el cual consiste en que realizo una consulta a la base de datos para obtener un dato y despues realizo un condicion si se cumple quiero mostrar un mensaje debajo del input
mas abajo explico como uso el js para mostrar los mensaje debajo de input en otros archivos

este es mi archivo html el cual tengo un select que obtiene los valores de la base de datos

```
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head> 
    <title>Ejemplo</title>
</head>
<form method="post">
                    <fieldset class="conductor mb-5">
                        <div class="form-group row container">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 etiquetas">VEHICULO</label>
                            <div class="col-8 col-sm-2 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                <select id="placa" name="placa" class="form-control xa"">
                                    <option>CAMION</option>
                                    <?php
                                    $query1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT ca_id,ca_placa From camion where ca_estado=1");
                                    while ($placa = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
                                    ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $placa['ca_id'] ?>"> <?php echo utf8_encode($placa['ca_placa']) ?> </option>
                                    <?php
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                                <span id="errorplaca" class="error"></span>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary mb-5 boton" type="submit" name="boton" value="GUARDAR"
                         onclick="return validar_vehiculo(this.form)">GUARDAR</button>
                     </fieldset>
</form>
```

en mi archivo javascript( se llama validar_vehiculo) uso este tipo de validaciones la cuales me permite mostrar un mensaje debajo del input
esta es una funcion de otro archivo  quiero una funcion asi que muestre debajo de input pero en el documento php

```
function validar_camion_vehiculo(formulario) {
    if (formulario.placa.value == "CAMION") {
        document.getElementById("errorplaca").innerText = "ingrese camion";
        formulario.placa.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

mi archivo php lo esta así

```
<?php
$placa = $_POST["placa"];
if (isset($_POST["boton"])) {

    $VBoton = $_POST["boton"];
    if ($VBoton == "GUARDAR") {

$validar_vehiculo = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM vehiculo where ca_id='$placa'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($validar_vehiculo) > 0) {
//aqui quiero tener una validacion asi como la de arriba 
//me muestre un mensaje debajo de input 


echo '</script>';
```

Comment: El código PHP se ejecuta en el servidor, y el código JavaScript en el cliente. No puedes ejecutar PHP del lado cliente así como no puedes ejecutar JavaScript en PHP (servidor).

Comment: Es como dice @MauricioContreras, sin embargo, no hay que lamentarse por ello. Cada cosa en su sitio, como debe ser: lo del cliente en el cliente y lo del servidor en el servidor, pero eso no significa que sean dos elementos extraños, sino destinados a trabajar juntos, por eso existen herramientas para comunicar entre cliente y servidor: Ajax, o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript. Debes usar esas herramientas cuando quieras pasar datos de un lado a otro.

Comment: Puedes utilizar Ajax  para enviar y recibir la data de php como te menciono @A.Cedano, con JQuery decides que hacer con la data y en donde.

Comment: @AntonioGalicia señalar que jQuery NO es Ajax, y puedes usarla sin jQuery, la cual es una librería que implementa Ajax y que lo hace más fácil, sobre todo si estás iniciando, pero [Ajax en sí misma](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) es una combinación de varias herramientas como  HTML o XHTML, CSS, JavaScript, DOM, XML, XSLT y el objeto XMLHttpRequest. Existe una herramienta más  moderna parecida a Ajax, que es la [API Fetch de Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), que sirve también para pasar cosas entre cliente y servidor.